# How to POST list of Product by WebClient or HttpClient and how to whire WebAPI controller for it?

Tags: c#, list, http-post, webclient, asp.net-web-api

I have WebAPI controller's method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ChangeProducts(List<Product> products)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

And I try to send a list by WebClient:

```
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            string sl = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products);
            var  r = wc.UploadString(_orderServiceUrl, sl);
        }
```

or by HttpClient:

```
        using (var hc = new HttpClient())
        {
            var val = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products);

            hc.BaseAddress = new Uri(_orderServiceUrl);
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage r = hc.PostAsync(_orderServiceUrl, new StringContent(val)).Result;
        }
```

But in controller the list is empty (not null, but no items).

Why?

Comment: Are you sure your list contains elements?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, yes. There are elements.

Comment: Please add the declaration of your product class and show us the generated JSON

Comment: {"CurrencyCode":null,"DeliveryKey":"X:1:2:1:1:23","EstimatedShippingDate":"2014-11-22T12:10:27.2342536Z","GuaranteedShippingDate":"2014-10-23T12:10:27.2342536Z","OfferKey":"A0041:JS:HINO:AFL","OrderId":828,"Price":316.9100,"Quantity":1,"QuantityLot":0,"QuantityUnit":null,"SellerOrderKey":null,"State":"NotAddedInBasket","StateComment":null,"UserId":2}

Comment: It is JSON with the same with model's property names.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It works:

```
using (var hc = new HttpClient())
{
    hc.BaseAddress = new Uri(_orderServiceUrl);
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = hc.PostAsJsonAsync("", products).Result;
}
```

Comment: Dont use `Task.Result`. It may lead to a deadlock. Look into a synchronous api using `WebClient`.

Comment: Tnx, but it is for example. I use async/await methods.